# How to get element with specific value in htmlagilitypack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack

I have ASP.NET MVC4 project where try to parse html document with HtmlAgilityPack. I have the following HTML:

```
<td class="pl22">
  <p class='pb10 pt10 t_grey'>Experience:</p>
  <p class='bold'>any</p>
</td>
<td class='pb10 pl20'>
  <p class='t_grey pb10 pt10'>Education:</p>
  <p class='bold'>any</p>
</td>
<td class='pb10 pl20'>
  <p class='pb10 pt10 t_grey'>Schedule:</p>
  <p class='bold'>part-time</p>
  <p class='text_12'>2/2 (day/night)</p>
</td>
```

I need to get values:

1. "any" after "Experience:"
2. "any" after "Education:"
3. "part-time", "2/2 (day/night)" after "Schedule:"

All what I imagine is that

```
HtmlNode experience = hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='pl22']//p[@class='bold']");
```

But it get me different element, which place in the top of the page. My Experience, Education and Schedule is static values. In additional my any, any part-time day/night is the dynamic values. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an alternative which is more focused on the table headers (`Experience`, `Education` and `Schedule`), instead of the node classes:

```
private static List<string> GetValues(HtmlDocument doc, string header) {
    return doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("//p[contains(text(), '{0}')]/following-sibling::p", header)).Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();
}
```

You can call that method like this:

```
var experiences = GetValues(doc, "Experience");
var educations = GetValues(doc, "Education");
var schedules = GetValues(doc, "Schedule");

experiences.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
educations.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
schedules.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Thank you, your example more agile.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this if you want to keep the XPath

```
var html = "<td class='pl22'><p class='pb10 pt10 t_grey'>Experience:</p><p class='bold'>any</p></td><td class='pb10 pl20'><p class='t_grey pb10 pt10'>Education:</p><p class='bold'>any</p></td><td class='pb10 pl20'><p class='pb10 pt10 t_grey'>Schedule:</p><p class='bold'>part-time</p><p class='text_12'>2/2 (day/night)</p></td> ";

var doc = new HtmlDocument
{
     OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};

doc.LoadHtml(html);

var part1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='pl22']/p[@class='bold']");
var part2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='pb10 pl20']/p[@class='bold']");

foreach (var item in part2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}

var part3 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='pb10 pl20']/p[@class='text_12']");

Console.WriteLine(part1.InnerText);            
Console.WriteLine(part3.InnerText);
```

Output :

```
any
part-time
any
2/2 (day/night)
```

Comment: I cant get values with your method. I get different values